# Login Com Certificado Digital ( E-CPF, E-CNPJ ) com Servlet / JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlet, certificado-digital

Olá.

Estou querendo desenvolver um sistema de Login similar ao que os portais do governo usam ( E-CAC, NFE e similares ), onde é usado o E-CNPJ para logar.

Fiz o seguinte:

**1) Criei e assinei uma chave privada RSA para o servidor:**

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  
keytool -selfcert -alias tomcat
```

**2) Configurei o tomcat:**

```
<Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"  
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"  
    keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="password"  
    clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Funcionou perfeitamente e pude acessar https://localhost:8443/

**3) Instalei a cadeia ICP-Brasil**

Segui exatamente os passos descritos aqui: http://www.iti.gov.br/noticias/188-atualizacao/473...-cadeia-icpbrasil-java-windows

**4) Implementei o Servlet:**

```
@WebServlet(name = "LerCertificado", urlPatterns = {"/lercertificado"})  
public class LerCertificado extends HttpServlet {  

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");  
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {  
            out.println("<html>");  
            out.println("<head><title>ServletLerCertificado</title></head>");  
            out.println("<body>");  
            out.println("<p>Certificado digital:</p>");  
            String cipherSuite = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite");  
            if (cipherSuite != null) {  
                java.security.cert.X509Certificate certChain[] = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]) request  
                        .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");  

                if (certChain != null) {  
                    System.out.println("Array size: " + certChain.length);  
                    for (int i = 0; i < certChain.length; i++) {  
                        String certInfo = "Client Certificate [" + i + "] = "  
                                + certChain[i].toString();  
                        out.println(certInfo);  
                    }  
                } else {  
                    out.println("Cliente sem Certificado Digital 1");  
                }  
            } else {  
                out.println("Cliente sem Certificado Digital 2");  
            }  
            out.println("</body></html>");  
        }  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        processRequest(request, response);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
        processRequest(request, response);  
    }   

}
```

Porém NÃO FUNCIONA. 
Sempre cai na parte "Cliente sem Certificado Digital 1"

Cheguei a testar em um servidor AWS (Só não fiz o passo 3) com certificado SSL válido e também não deu certo.

Alguma ideia do que pode estar errado?

Comment: Todos estes sites usam certificados digital para conectar você pode não ter um certificado digital no modelo A1 e por isso esta retornado a mensagem:
"Cliente sem Certificado Digital 1".